# _itoa_s Function show error on Android studio native c++

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, android-native-library

[image]

**My Code:**

```java
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < final_numbers.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < final_numbers[i].second.size(); j++) {
        char add_c[6];
        _itoa_s(final_numbers[i].second[j], add_c, 6, 16);
        qr_code_string.append(add_c);
        qr_code_string.append("-");
    }
}
```

I am trying to run my c++ program on Android studio Native-NDK.
But the compiler shows me this error. **use of undeclared identifier '_itoa_s'**

Does anybody have any solution?

Comment: `_itoa_s` looks like a Microsoft specific thing to me. Don't you *actually* want to use [std::itoa](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead?

Answer (score 0):

That's because… it *is* undeclared!

`_itoa_s` is not a standard function. The clue is the leading underscore. You've used some platform-specific thing (probably [Microsoft extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/itoa-s-itow-s?view=vs-2019); on that page it is stated: *"These functions are Microsoft-specific. For more compatibility information, see Compatibility"*), then found that it's not portable to another platform.

You could use [`std::itoa`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead. Make sure that the behaviour you were relying on before is still there, or can be accomplished in some other way.